# where can i find documents for WebSocket.Server.on method?

Tags: javascript, websocket, ws

I am learning WebSocket in JavaScript,  using [ws][1] and I read most of the Docs, related to it, but i couldn't find any Documents for "on" method or function,
As i like to know how this "on" method works.
if anyone are familiar with this "on" method, in the WebSocket.Server , i would appreciate it, if could help me with it.
for example in the Docs, there is this code :

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');

const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 8080 });

wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
  ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {
     console.log('received: %s', message);
  }); 
  ws.send('something');
});
```

but i couldnt find any suitable Docs for "on" method.
[1]: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are aliases for the different `on` handlers. For example

```
ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {
```

is (nearly) equivalent to

```
ws.onmessage = function incoming(message) {
```

The same thing applies to the [other possible socket events](https://github.com/websockets/ws/blob/HEAD/doc/ws.md#websocketonclose): `close`, `error`, and `open`.

So, to find out how `on('someString'` works, look for `onsomeString` in the docs.

This is very similar to the interface for event listeners in HTML. You can do

```
someElement.onclick = function() {
```

But you can also do (nearly equivalently)

```
someElement.addEventListener('click', function() {
```

where what comes after the `on` is the event name that can be passed to `addEventListener`.

Comment: Thank you, i wanted to know its exact purpose,  so you mean "on" method, is similar to addEventListener . and waiting for that specified event. am i right?

Comment: Yes, `ws.on('message',` is like `ws.onmessage` in the same way that `.addEventListener('click'` is like `.onclick`